# "Element ol not allowed as child of element pre in this context."

Tags: css, html, nested-lists

I am working on an HTML assignment for class, but keep getting the following error when I try to validate my webpage: "Element ol not allowed as child of element pre in this context." Any suggestions on how to fix this problem? The section of HTML is posted below:

```
<pre class="proterozoic"  style="background-color: #FF99CC">
<ol class="era">
    <li>Proterozoic</li>
</ol>
</pre>
<pre class="paleozoic" style="background-color: #0099FF">
<ol class="era">
    <li>Paleozoic</li>
        <ol class="period">
        <li>Cambrian</li>
            <li>Ordovician</li>
            <li>Silurian</li>
            <li>Devonian</li>
            <li>Mississippian</li>
            <li>Pennsylvanian</li>
            <li>Permian</li>
        </ol>
</ol>
</pre>
<pre class="mesozoic" style="background-color: #66CC66">
<ol class="era">
    <li>Mesozoic</li>
        <ol class="period">
            <li>Triassic</li>
            <li>Jurassic</li>
            <li>Cretaceous</li>
        </ol>
</ol>
</pre>
<pre class="cenozoic" style="background-color: #FF3333">
<ol class="era">
    <li>Cenozoic</li>
        <ol class="period">
        <li>Paleogene</li>
                <ol class="epoch">
            <li>Paleocene</li>
                    <li>Eocene</li>
                    <li>Oligocene</li>
                </ol>
        <li>Neogene</li>
                <ol class="epoch">
                <li>Miocene</li>
                    <li>Pliocene</li>
                    <li>Pleistocene</li>
                    <li>Holocene</li>
                </ol>
        </ol>
</ol>
</pre>
```

Comment: Does your assignment require you to use `<pre>`? If you are just trying to set the background color for those lists I would use `<div>` or `<span>` with the same style attributes. I'm pretty sure `<pre>` is for HTML preformatted text.

Comment: Changing it do <div> worked. <pre> was not a requirement, the professor just mentioned that's what he used so that was what I tried, but now I have a new error which is described in the comment that is in the answer posted below. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<pre>` element is for preformatted text, so you can't put additional formatting tags inside it.

By the look of things, you would be better off using `<div>` elements instead. If you want them all to appear in a `typewriter font`, you can add `div { font-family:monospace; }` to your CSS template.

---

The nesting of the lists can be fixed by keeping the nested `<ol>` elements inside the parent `<li>` elements, like this:

```
<ol class="era">
    <li>Paleozoic
        <ol class="period">
            <li>Cambrian</li>
            <li>Ordovician</li>
            <li>Silurian</li>
            <li>Devonian</li>
            <li>Mississippian</li>
            <li>Pennsylvanian</li>
            <li>Permian</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: That fixed the error I was having, but now I have a new error. It says that I can't have an <ol> element as a child to another <ol> element. For the assignment though I have to have roman numerals, then alphabets, followed by decimal numbers like in an outline and the only way i know to do this is to use nested ordered lists....?

Comment: The submenu `<ol>` shuould be inside an `<li>`. You closed the `<li>` before the submenu when you should close it after.

Comment: ahh! Thanks. I didn't even think about the order in which I closed the tags. You guys rock!